# How to convert URL() to path() in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-urls

```
url_patterns=[
        url(r'^(?P<postid>\d+)/preference/(?P<userpreference>\d+)/$', views.postpreference, name='postpreference'),
]
```

I got this code from Stack Overflow only but I know only `path()` but don't know `url()`

I tried to understand and convert this `url(r'^......)` to `path(...)` using [url() to path()](https://consideratecode.com/2018/05/02/django-2-0-url-to-path-cheatsheet/)

But I also want to know how to use `"\d+"` in `path()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\d+` is generally used for integers, so use [the `<int:>` converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters):

```
path('<int:postid>/preference/<int:userpreference>/', views.postpreference, name='postpreference'),
```